# How to get values of static variables from a function in php?

Tags: php, static

I need to get values of static variables from a function, example:

a,b,c,d,e,f,g are static variables in function test()

test().a or test("a"), should return the value of static var a

test().b or test("b"), should return the value of static var b

and so on!

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do this. If you need this, you shouldn't be using static variables in the first place.

Comment: @Barmer There's a way to do it, but I can't see why one would want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think why you need this, but here you go:

```
<?php

function fnc($var){
  static $a = 1;
  static $b = 2;
  return $$var;
}
echo fnc("a").",".fnc("b")."\n";  // 1,2
```

For `$$var` see [Variable Variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Demo at https://3v4l.org/2CqSu

Comment: It works, thank you. (Is the double dollar supported in any php version?)

Comment: @user At least as far back as v4.3, but you should be using v8 for new code anyway. See https://3v4l.org/2CqSu

Comment: I learned something today, thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Dot (`.`) is a string concatenation, I don't see how you can override it in PHP. You can use `->` instead:

```
function weird($var = null)
{
    static $a = 'a', $b = 'b', $c = 'c', $d = 'd', $e = 'e';
    
    if (func_num_args())
    {
        return $$var;
    }
    
    return (object) get_defined_vars();
}

$result = weird('a') . weird()->b . weird('c');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will use the double dollar solution for what I need.